# In Swift, can I use function type in tuple?

Tags: swift, tuples

I want to use an array of tuples containing a function type. For example:

```
(Int,Bool,() -> () )
```

I then create the array:

```
var someList = [(Int,Bool,() -> () )]()
```

But at compile time there are 2 errors on this statement:

- `Expected ',' separator`
- `Expected expression in list of expressions`

So is it possible to use a *function type* on a tuple or do I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
typealias TupleType = (Int, Bool, () -> Void)
var list = [TupleType]()
```

Unfortunately, trying to access an item in a tuple from the array
results in Playgrounds breaking - 'Communication with the Playground service was unexpectedly interupted'. Trying the same thing in a project results in a segmentation fault. If you're getting the same problem I would recommend you use a struct instead:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let num: Int
    let bool: Bool
    let closure: () -> Void

    init(num: Int, bool: Bool, closure: () -> Void = {}) {
        self.num = num
        self.bool = bool
        self.closure = closure
    }
}

var list = [MyStruct]()
list.append(MyStruct(num: 1, bool: true, closure: { println("Hello") }))
list.append(MyStruct(num: 2, bool: false))
```

Comment: Adding  a third parameter to an already existing tuple was the far direct way to improve existing code. Unfortunately it leeds us to some *twilight zone* so using struct instead is a better solution.

Comment: In your example, can you describe how to define a value of `MyStruct` type with a `closure` component set to a no statement function?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'no statement function'?

Comment: A function that does nothing, with no statement in it.

Comment: Does that answer your question? :) As an alternative you could make the closure optional.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.Thank you. Using `struct` is a far more elegant and evolutive solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two problems here: 1) requirement to use `typealias` for function types in tuple declarations, 2) compiler bug with dereferencing functions stored in tuples.

### 1. Adding a function

The compiler doesn't like finding function signatures in the tuple declarations. This feels like a bug to me, but I don't know the Swift specification well enough to say for sure.

```
typealias VoidToVoid = () -> ()

var c = [Int, Bool, VoidToVoid]()  // works
var d = [Int, Bool, () -> ()]()    // syntax error
```

### 2. The compiler segfaults when trying to dereference the function.

```
func performSideEffects() {
    println("Howdy")
}

c.append(1, true, performSideEffects)  // works
c.count  // works
c[0].2   // blows up. Although possible completions with correct type shows up

0  swift                    0x00000001020272b8 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x0000000102027794 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8131ff1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5e2f0550 _sigtramp + 3707569744
4  swift                    0x00000001019ea39d swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9901
5  swift                    0x0000000101954f4f swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 159
6  swift                    0x00000001019d4c59 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::Module*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 2121
7  swift                    0x00000001019d5693 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 51
8  swift                    0x0000000101911087 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 6647
9  swift                    0x000000010190f4e6 main + 1814
10 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff829f15c9 start + 1
11 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000003b start + 2103503475
```

Comment: I should add, "use a struct" as answered by ABakerSmith seems like a good way to do this, if you need this capability in Swift 1.2. I was intrigued by this question in terms of a Swift puzzle to solve. I didn't think it would lead to a compiler error.

Comment: This is weird: I don't have the syntax errors you mention while using parentheses: `var actionsList = [SKNode,SKAction]()`.

Comment: Oh man. You're right about that bogus syntax issue, there's no error, and I was wrong. I had a different typo that I kept reproducing due to copy-paste blindness. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Trying this code in my own code leads to a compile error: 'Expression resolves to an unused l-value'. Adding `()' at the end of the statement to obtain `c[0].2()` leads to the same results you obtained: compiler segfaults